# PresentViewController takes a lot of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a really strange situation: a view controller, called by `presentViewController` takes a lot of time to load. I mean that *preparation* stage takes a lot of time, though whole animation performed quickly. Going back from the presented controller to the previous one is fine.

What clues to I have?

First af all, I *prepared* my next view controller in first `viewWillAppear`:

```
METAddEventViewController *controller = [self.storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addEventView"];

self.nextController =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
```

Where `self.nextController` is nonatomic and strong.

So, my method that calls the next controller is pretty simple:

```
- (IBAction)addMeetingButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.addMeetingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addMeeting-pressed@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self presentViewController:self.nextController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed");
}]; 
}
```

`METAddEventViewController` is just a `UITableViewController` with static cells of 4: 2 Basic cells, 1 cell with `UIDatePicker` and 1 with `UITextView`.

So, my `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.appointMeetingButton.enabled = NO;

self.title = @"Create Meeting";

self.commentaryView.delegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
self.commentaryView.text = @"Enter comment for the meeting if needed";
self.commentaryViewFilled = NO;
self.commentaryView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateSelectedPersonCalled:)
                                             name:@"updateSelectedPersonLabel"
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateSelectedPersonCalled:)
                                             name:@"updateSelectedLocationLabel"
                                           object:nil];


[self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(meetingAppointable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
```

I ran Profiling and noticed that the most time consuming operations are allocation ones. Though, both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` of `METAddEventController` are fine - about 10 ms. Most of the time in *them* takes configuring `self.commentaryView`

What can I do? Which additional information can I present to find the solution?

Comment: Try calling [self.nextController view]; just after init. Objective-C initializes the view just before it's needed, not directly after init. This line should force it to initialize the view instantly.

Comment: @PrzemysławWrzesiński I added it both to `controller` and `nextController` it seems to decrease time from 2.0s to 1.6s. Still this hang is visible

Comment: Hmm it is indeed a strange issue. Perhaps the button function is not executed in the main thread? Please try:
     `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:self.nextController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });`

Comment: No changes. However, I noticed that it decreases from 1.6 to 1.2, when loaded once more like Add->Go back->Add

Comment: I'd say it takes 0.4s to really load then, and 1.2s doing something strange, no idea what it is though :) Could You post the init method?

Comment: it doesn't have explicit init method.

Comment: OK, another thing to try: could You set the animation to NO? Does it load instantly then, or still takes time?

Comment: Well, I tried both and it seems to go faster without animation. Next, I removed setting addMeeting image to better UI. Now the question: is any way to decrease delay of animation?

Comment: This seems a silly way to set the button image when pressed:
`[self.addMeetingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addMeeting-pressed@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`. You should configure the button to have the image already set up for `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Comment: Yep, I changed to `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing it in the action method though. You should do it in the .xib / storyboard (if there is one). Or you should do it programatically wherever you initialise the button.

Comment: I moved it to  `viewDidLoad`